# Windows store publishing bug or something else

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying update my published beta app on MS store. I just replace package file. But Submission steel not approved or declined. I waiting 5 days and any changes. Who know any MS support email where I can ask what wrong with app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get support on Microsoft's Site. Select '`App submission and certification`' type and select your category, then you can send your info to microsoft.

The link is here: [Microsoft Support](https://getsupport.microsoft.com/default.aspx?locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&ccfcode=us&mkt=en-us&pesid=14654&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&tenant=store&supporttopic_L1=31762159&ccsid=635384694777242084&scrx=1)